# Mysql query help

Tags: mysql, count, conditional-statements, sum, join

My system consists of two user types - Students and Tutors.
  - Tutors can create classes and packs
  - Both Students and tutors can purchase classes and packs

Following are the tables involved

`Groups`
`Users`- Contains common fields of both user types
`Tutor_Details`- Tutor specific fields
`WebClasses` - Classes created by tutors
`Learning_Packs` - Packs created by tutors
`Orders` - One record per purchase
`Order_Details` - Multiple records per purchase - as many items in purchase
`Payments`

The following query produces the list of all users(students and tutors) and displays the 3 fields- User name, `orders` - number of items purchased and `topics` - total number of classes and packs created -

```
SELECT u.name,
       COUNT(DISTINCT( o.id_order ))                                         AS
       orders,
       ( ( COUNT(DISTINCT( wc.id_wc )) ) + ( COUNT(DISTINCT( lp.id_lp )) ) ) AS
       topics
FROM   users AS u
       LEFT JOIN tutor_details AS td
         ON u.id_user = td.id_user
       INNER JOIN groups AS g
         ON u.id_group = g.id_group
       LEFT JOIN webclasses AS wc
         ON td.id_tutor = wc.id_author
       LEFT JOIN learning_packs AS lp
         ON td.id_tutor = lp.id_author
       LEFT JOIN orders AS o
         ON ( u.id_user = o.id_user )
       LEFT JOIN order_details AS od
         ON ( o.id_order = od.id_order )
       LEFT JOIN payments AS p
         ON ( o.id_order = p.id_order )
WHERE  IF(o.id_order != 0, o.order_status = 'paid', 1)
       AND IF(p.id_payment != 0, p.payment_status = 'success', 1)
GROUP  BY u.id_user
ORDER  BY u.id_user ASC
```

**Help needed**
Now, I want to add another filter/condition to the `topics` counting. Only those topics should be counted for which wc.status=1 or lp.status=1. I wish to do the same in a single query. Please note that the condition cannot be added inside the main where block (before the group block) because the query must still display students (who have not taken any class) and tutors who have taken classes with id_status = 0.

The `topics` count should only consider the classes/packs condition, that's all I want. The query should still display all the users as displayed by the present query.

Thanks,
Sandeepan

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, I found the solution myself before anyone else :)

```
SELECT u.id_user,
       ( Concat(u.name, ' ', u.surname) )                                AS name
       ,
       u.login,
       u.status,
       u.email,
       g.name                                                            AS TYPE
       ,
       u.joined,
       COUNT(DISTINCT( o.id_order ))                                     AS
       orders,
       ( COUNT(DISTINCT( IF(wc.id_status = 1, wc.id_wc, NULL) )) +
           COUNT(DISTINCT( IF(lp.id_status = 1, lp.id_lp, NULL) )) ) AS
       topics
FROM   users AS u
       LEFT JOIN tutor_details AS td
         ON u.id_user = td.id_user
       INNER JOIN groups AS g
         ON u.id_group = g.id_group
       LEFT JOIN webclasses AS wc
         ON td.id_tutor = wc.id_author
       LEFT JOIN learning_packs AS lp
         ON td.id_tutor = lp.id_author
       LEFT JOIN orders AS o
         ON ( u.id_user = o.id_user )
       LEFT JOIN order_details AS od
         ON ( o.id_order = od.id_order )
       LEFT JOIN payments AS p
         ON ( o.id_order = p.id_order )
WHERE  IF(o.id_order != 0, o.order_status = 'paid', 1)
       AND IF(p.id_payment != 0, p.payment_status = 'success', 1)
GROUP  BY u.id_user
ORDER  BY u.id_user ASC
```